# Why Angry Birds App doesn't load / open?

Tags: crashes, angry-birds

I have a [Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B](http://www.prestigio.com/news/new-products/MultiPad-7.0-Ultra) and for some reason I can not play the [Angry Birds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds) app on it.

I have downloaded the app from the Google Play Store but when I try to play it the screen goes blank for approx 3-4 seconds, as if the game was loading but then it just returns to the home screen of my device.

I have uninstalled & re-installed the device several times but to no avail.
I have even done a factory reset of my device but again no luck.

*This tablet was bought for the specific purpose of playing games now that the kids favorite app does not work there are two very disappointed children at home.*

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your device cannot cope with the native code being run by the Angry Birds app.

Developers can include native C/C++ code in their apps, and these are compiled per processor.

If part of this native code crashes, or cannot run, then the app or game closes - without a force close. This is what is happening here by the sound of it.

I have looked up the specs of your tablet, and it looks like you have a good processor - Angry Birds should be able to run well.

THe first thing you should check is that you have enough RAM left on your device to run the game - go to `System Settings->Apps->Running` and ensure that the `Free RAM` value is relatively high (30MB or greater). If it isn't, then you should remove some memory hogging applications.

If the RAM isn't the issue, then you should uninstall the game, and reinstall it. If that fails to work, then you should contact the maker of the game with your devices logcat data.

Comment: How can I obtain my device's log data?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue was with Google Play settings.

The majority of the time, the loading froze at the 'logging in' stage, so I figured it was an issue with my profile (password etc.). I went into my user account, opened my google account and disabled all of the 'sync' options. The game has loaded fine now for a couple of days.

Hope this helps anyone =)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I think you should try contacting Rovio about support for your phone. I had a pretty obscure phone, and Angry Birds didn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run any kind of Adblocker, auto task killer or Firewall on the Minipad? Also, how are you doing for capacity on RAM, internal and external storage?

I believe when Angry Birds first launches it's; Loading the app contents, loading any ad info, and probably communicating back to their servers to check for any updates.

With all that going on, potential pitfalls could be:

1. Running out of space in RAM, Internal Storage or External Storage. If you've got just enough space to install the app, but then run out while it's trying to write/cache more data, that could potentially cause it to crash.
2. If you have a Firewall running and haven't cleared the app to go through it, this could potentially cause a communications failure fault.
3. Ad Blockers shouldn't really bomb the app, but it's worth trying to see if the app runs with it disabled.
4. If you're running any kind of auto task killer, make sure to add the app as being allowed to run.